# How to enable SSI in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04, server-side-includes

I have an html page with SSI and I was trying for enabling SSI in my apache (V 2.4.18) running on Ubuntu 16.04. As per the guidelines [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html), I tried editing /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file and now included following directives,

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options FollowSymLinks
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml 
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But SSI is not working. Can anyone give direction?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable mod_include, execute this form terminal:

```
sudo a2enmod include 
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```